# Why do I get 502 when trying to authenticate

Tags: keycloak, jboss-tools

I'm trying to implement authentication for my UI application
I'm using https://github.com/joaojosefilho/vuejsOidcClient which I succesffully configured to work with gluu auth server

Now I wanted to try with keycloak 
what happens is that flow is started with which looks ok

`http://auth.solidsense.tk/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=console&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fportal.solidsense.tk%2Fcallback.html&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20permission%20address%20roles&state=f60457ff91c84ac5b49179bc4b47cd8d&nonce=3753dd32c3ea4f8087608382c2eef932`

and keycloak login page is presented but after entering credentials on submit I get error 502 for the following request ( if incorrect credentials are entered proper error messages is shown )

`http://auth.solidsense.tk/auth/realms/master/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=2xol67J32yIFVfDfrN0DmIT1sdzfzoeo1dg_kPZrYeY&execution=499b2298-5c08-4521-8993-b23eb253f0a4&client_id=console&tab_id=cHj4HozAr-Q`

this is the exception that I see in the log

```
08:03:26,164 DEBUG [io.undertow.request.io] (default task-1) UT005013: An IOException occurred: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer                                                
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)                                                                                                                        
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)                                                                                                                           
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)                                                                                                                                           
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)                                                                                                                     
        at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:289)                                                                                                                     
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127)                                                                                            
        at io.undertow.util.ConnectionUtils.doDrain(ConnectionUtils.java:96)                                                                                                                 
        at io.undertow.util.ConnectionUtils.cleanClose(ConnectionUtils.java:74)                                                                                                              
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.exchangeComplete(HttpReadListener.java:368)                                                                                     
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpServerConnection.exchangeComplete(HttpServerConnection.java:232)                                                                             
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.invokeExchangeCompleteListeners(HttpServerExchange.java:1279)                                                                               
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.terminateResponse(HttpServerExchange.java:1563)                                                                                             
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.terminateResponse(Connectors.java:147)                                                                                                              
        at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ServerFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.channelFinished(ServerFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:58)                                                   
        at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.exitFlush(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:316)                                                                
        at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.flush(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:234)                                                                    
        at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.flush(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:162)                                                                                               
        at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.flush(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:119)                                                                                      
        at org.xnio.channels.Channels.flushBlocking(Channels.java:63)                                                                                                                        
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:618)                                                                                          
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:486)                                                                           
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:575)                                                                                   
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:351)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

08:03:27,805 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
08:03:27,806 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
08:03:27,811 DEBUG [org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.changes.sessions.PersisterLastSessionRefreshStore] (Timer-2) Updating 0 userSessions with lastSessionRefresh: 1557813747
08:03:27,812 DEBUG [org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl] (Timer-2) Hibernate RegisteredSynchronization successfully registered with JTA pla
tform
```

If i try to access /auth/realms/master/account  there is no problem but that uses authorization code flow

`http://auth.solidsense.tk/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=account&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fauth.solidsense.tk%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Fmaster%2Faccount%2Flogin-redirect&state=0%2F2758cd0b-d1c0-4fd6-8c0f-a8aa1916aad6&response_type=code&scope=openid`

keycloak is running behind nginx

```
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name auth.solidsense.tk;
  location /{ 
    proxy_set_header Host $host; 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
```

I expect that after the clicking the submit button and after keycloak validates username and password to get redirected to my applications redirect_uri

Comment: What do you see in nginx error log?

Comment: I have the similar issue.  Did you find out the reason?

Answer (score 46):

I got this same 502 error.

Nginx error log was reporting "*1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream,". Increasing the buffer size fixed the issue.

Add these directives to the `http` block in nginx.conf

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a lifesaver! Not all 3 directives are always necessary, however, this article helped us tune it for our specific situation: https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx.

Answer (score 35):

For those of you that are dealing with Nginx Kubernetes ingress:

```
"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size": "128k"
```

More info here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#proxy-buffer-size

Answer (score 11):

The problem might be in Nginx configuration. Try setting proxy_buffers to a higher number. e.g.:

```
listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name auth.solidsense.tk;
  location /{ 
    proxy_set_header Host $host; 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffers 4 16k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Root cause is low nginx proxy buffer size. You need to increase it, for example 128k. If you are using kubernetes ingress like me, you can use the following settings.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-keycloak
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - keycloak.mesutpiskin.com
    secretName:  wildcard-fimple
  rules:
  - host: keycloak.mesutpiskin.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-keycloak
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Answer (score 2):

for anyone deploying with the official nginx-ingress chart from https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nginx/nginx-ingress, the annotation is `nginx.org/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"`

Answer (score 0):

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` is what did it for me

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Ingress Controller on Kubernetes:
Update Config Map that corresponds to the Ingress Controller, in my case ingress-nginx-controller, as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
.......
.....
data:
  .........
  proxy-buffer-size: 128k
  proxy_buffers: 4 256k
  proxy_busy_buffers_size: 256k
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration was the one that worked for me on bitnami helm chart.

`annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"´

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?