# I'm getting 502 when trying to authenticate via keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, aws-application-load-balancer

I have exactly the same problem described here [Why do I get 502 when trying to authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126864/why-do-i-get-502-when-trying-to-authenticate) and the possible solution could be https://stackoverflow.com/a/68811151 but I use `AWS Load Balancer Controller` and unfortunately it does not support `proxy-buffer-size` annotation.

So, is there any workaround to set `proxy-buffer-size` in `ALB`?

Comment: Please increase the buffer size and try again.

Comment: How to do it in context of ALB?